# Should each element of a 2d array create a new Sprite object?

Tags: c++, arrays, multidimensional-array, sprite, tile

I'm trying to create a tilemap with a 2d array and was struggling slightly with it. When I iterate through the array should I create a new Sprite object for each element in the array or is it possible to just create a sprite object for each of the different tiles then copy them to the relevant positions on screen. For example - note Rows and Columns are const ints already initialised to 5

```
    int MazeMap[Rows][Columns] = { //Should the array type be int or Sprite*
{1, 1, 1, 1, 1}, 
{1, 0, 0, 0, 1}, 
{1, 0, 1, 1, 1}, 
{1, 0, 0, 0, 1}, 
{1, 1, 1, 1, 1}
};
for(int x = 0; x<Rows; x++)
{  
   for(int y = 0; y<Columns; y++)
   { 
      if(MazeMap[x][y]==1)
      {
        //should I create a new Sprite object here or should I create
        // a Tile1 sprite object above the array and then just pass it into
        //this array to draw it to the screen?
       }
   }
}
```

To me it just seems really inefficient to have (in this case) 25 sprite objects when you can just have 2 sprite objects and copy them to a number of different locations on screen.

Comment: It depends on how your sprite is implemented.

Comment: Please explain precisely what your Sprite actually is and what do you mean by "create" and "draw"? What is the logic you are trying to implement? If your point is to execute some specific action for each maze element equal to "1", you should just use the appropriate function inside your IF condition.

Comment: It may be possible to create the sprite objects in place. More information required to provide a usable answer.

Comment: Ok, so the Sprite object is a class that is just going to load a small bitmap, then render it to the backbuffer (Render to backbuffer is what I meant by draw). By create I meant using the new keyword so `Sprite Tile = new Sprite(); ` command (Think I should have said create an instance of the sprite object to be more accurate ... My bad :| ). What I'm trying to do is render a wall bitmap where each element is equal to 1 and a grass bitmap where the element is equal to 0.  Hope I've made it somewhat clearer. @appleapple @PawełPtasznik @user4581301

Comment: if your sprite object don't keep the bitmap than there is no significant difference here. It's still not clear about your sprite class. What I can say is you should **load bitmap once** and use that for every draw (do this in sprite class or outer is not matter)